# Manually performing layout transitions of render pass attachments

Tags: graphics, vulkan

I know this is bad, but I'm asked to adopt to a given interface, which manually performs layout transitions of render targets before submit/present calls.

So, while I usually would want to specify (in the creation of the corresponding render pass) the `initialLayout` resp. `finalLayout` of the `VkAttachmentDescription` corresponding to such an render target to be `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED` resp. `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR` and the `layout` of the corresponding `VkAttachmentReference` to be `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL`, I have no idea how I should set these fields now.

It seems like there is no possibility to tell the API to perform a no-op, i.e. preserve the current layout of given the attachment.

(BTW, is there an analogue of D3D12's `D3D12_RESOURCE_STATES::D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_UNORDERED_ACCESS`?)

Comment: "D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_UNORDERED_ACCESS" What does that actually mean?

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm not sure whether you are really asking this as a question. If so, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/ne-d3d12-d3d12_resource_states). I actually don't know what it really means, since I'm not familiar with D3D12, but if I got the documentation right, then there is something like an "unordered access view" in D3D12 and I guess it corresponds to that.

Answer (score 0):

A "no-op" doesn't make sense. *You* must control the layout, and *you* are required to know the layout of every image you are using for any given purpose at the time you use it for that purpose. If you are working in code where someone else determines what the layout is, then those people need to tell you what layout those images are in (if you need the render pass image's data to be preserved, which is rather rare) and/or need to be in after the render pass.

If you're working with an API or code structure that does not give you this information, then *that* is what you need to change.

Comment: The existing interface is very similar to D3D12, where the initial and final layouts of render targets are not part of the pipeline description. So, there are calls like `OMSetRenderTargets` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/nf-d3d12-id3d12graphicscommandlist-omsetrendertargets) *after* pipeline creation. And layout transitions are manually performed via memory barriers for them.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: "*The existing interface is very similar to D3D12, where the initial and final layouts of render targets are not part of the pipeline description.*" Well, this is Vulkan; pipelines are built relative to subpasses of a particular render pass, so the layouts of the attachments are a hard-coded part of a pipeline. That's the API.

Comment: Yes, I know. It's not my decision. Do you have any suggestion how I should handle this?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: If this "interface" is completely unchangeable, if said interface has no idea whatsoever what layout the images are in or what layout it wants them in afterwards, then there's nothing you *can* do. Preserving the image data for the load-op (or really, doing *anything* with an image) *requires* knowing the image's layout. If the interface can't tell you what the layout is, and will not otherwise guarantee that layout, then you're out of luck.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: But I remind you that preserving the image data on load is not a common occurrence, so if it's happening, you need to ask yourself why you're doing that. As for the output, that still isn't going to work, because whoever's using the image next needs to know what layout to use for it. So unless it can tell you what layout to expect the image to be in, you're out of luck.

Comment: So, any layout transitions of render targets must be specified at render pass creation (i.e. at the latest when the pipeline is created), right?

Comment: Please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65266956/547231). Couldn't I simply set the initialLayout to `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR` and manually ensure that the image has this layout before the render pass begins?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: The problem you outlined in your question is that you *do not know* what the layout of the image is when you get it. Any manual layout transition *requires* specifying both the starting and ending layout. So you're just kicking the can down the road; you still don't know enough to do the transition, whether manual or automatic.