# Manually transition swap chain image layouts

Tags: graphics, vulkan

Say I have a render pass with a single color attachment corresponding to the images of a swap chain. Usually, I would set the `initialLayout` and `finalLayout` fields of the `VkAttachmentDescription` to `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED` and `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR`, respectively.

Now I would like to set the `initialLayout` to `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR` instead and perform the transition of a swap chain image to this state manually before the render pass begins.

I want to do this using memory barriers. So, given a generic function

```
void transition_image_layout(VkCommandBuffer command_buffer,
    VkImage image, VkImageLayout old_layout, VkImageLayout new_layout)
{
    VkAccessFlags src_access_mask,
        dst_access_mask;
    VkPipelineStageFlags src_stage_mask,
        dst_stage_mask;
        
    // set src_access_mask/dst_access_mask and
    // src_stage_mask/dst_stage_mask properly
    // according to old_layout/new_layout

    VkImageMemoryBarrier image_memory_barrier{};
    image_memory_barrier.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
    image_memory_barrier.srcAccessMask;
    image_memory_barrier.dstAccessMask;
    image_memory_barrier.oldLayout = old_layout;
    image_memory_barrier.newLayout = new_layout;
    image_memory_barrier.srcQueueFamilyIndex = src_queue_family_index;
    image_memory_barrier.dstQueueFamilyIndex = dst_queue_family_index;
    image_memory_barrier.image = image;
    image_memory_barrier.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    image_memory_barrier.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1; 
    image_memory_barrier.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;

    vkCmdPipelineBarrier(command_buffer, src_stage_mask, dst_stage_mask, 0, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 1, &image_memory_barrier);
}
```

at which point before, between and after `vkCmdBeginRenderPass` and `vkCmdEndRenderPass` would I need to perform the transition and which are the appropriate values for `src_access_mask/dst_access_mask` and `src_stage_mask/dst_stage_mask`?

Comment: "*perform the transition of a swap chain image to this state manually before the render pass begins*" ... why? Why not just let the render pass do the transition for you? The initial layout is the layout the image currently is in. In order to do *any* kind of layout transition (that preserves the image data), you *have to know* what layout the image is in. So just use that layout as the render pass's initial layout. The only reason to not do this is if the layout it will be provided in will actually change from point to point, but that suggests an incoherent engine design issue.

Comment: @NicolBolas I need to match an existing D3D12-like interface which is performing a manual memory barrier to transfer the layout from `D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PRESENT` to `D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RENDER_TARGET`. So, in contrast to what I wrote in the question, I think I would like to specify the `initialLayout` of my `VkAttachmentDescription` to be `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL`. Assuming that I know the current layout of my swap chain image, couldn't I manually transition to `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL` before the render pass begins?

Comment: You could, but if you know the layout, why would you? Unless the image might sometimes be in a different layout, there is no functional difference between that and just setting up the render pass properly. Equally importantly, if it's in the "src_present" layout, that means you have previously presented it, yes? If so, why do you want to preserve its contents? And if you don't want to preserve its contents, just mark the initial layout as undefined.

Comment: @NicolBolas Please take a look at [this article](https://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/EgorYusov/20181211/332596/Taking_State_Transitions_in_Vulkan_and_Direct3D12_under_Control_a_Diligent_Approach.php). They write "Note that Vulkan also exposes another form of synchronization called render passes and subpasses. The main purpose of render passes is to provide implicit synchronization guarantees such that an application does not need to insert a barrier after every single rendering command." This seems to indicate that a render pass is somehow a "optional" thing or do I get this wrong?

Comment: The article has it backwards. The "main purpose of render passes" is the *second* thing it says they do (the stuff about TBRs). Indeed, D3D12 provides the same "implicit synchronization guarantees" for rendering commands without a render pass system. And no, render passes are not optional in Vulkan.

Comment: @NicolBolas Is there a way to obtain the current layout of an image? I guess not, since the API seems to want that I keep track of the layout. However, in contrast to other images, the swap chain images are created by the API. Which layout do they have right after construction of the swap chain?

Comment: "*Is there a way to obtain the current layout of an image?*" How would you even define "current" in an API where you're building commands to be executed asynchronously on a computational unit distinct from the one asking the question? "*Which layout do they have right after construction of the swap chain?*" `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED`. It doesn't matter anyway, since its contents are undefined.